# How to convert a sub-string into an int from a string

Tags: java, int, substring

I have the following string in java

```
String str = "1 10 9 2 4 6 3 56 3 4 45 55";
```

I want to substring "1", "2", "3", "4" and so on.... and convert them into an integer array. I tried to find the index of " " spaces for a start and end to substring "1", "2", "3","4" and so on ...., but I was not successful. Please help.

Comment: We cannot help you with your code unless you include it to your question.

Comment: You may also want to consider using `split()` method of class `String`.

Comment: Why 1,2,3, and 4, what's special about them? Why not 6?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose from the fact that you only mention 1, 2, 3 and 4 as substrings that you only want to retrieve one-digit substrings. To do so, you first have to split on whitespace:

```
String[] split = str.split(' ')
```

Then you can retain all elements of the array with length 1:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String elem : split) {
    if (elem.length() == 1) {
        result.add(elem);
    }
}
```

Note that you can parse strings to integers using `Integer.parseInt(String str)`.

A different approach would be to extract one-digit numbers with a regex: `[^\s]([0-9])[$\s]`

Edit: Based on your given String, also 9 and 6 would land in the `result` List, as they are also one-digit numbers